# How I Avoid Country code in wordpress sms plugin subscription form?

Tags: php, wordpress, api, plugins, sms

I have install the wordpress sms plugin and setup it's setting but now in fornt end subscription form there is country code is compulsory in mobile number text box....

without the country code the message showing "Please Enter Valid Mobile Number...."
How could i solve this ???

I want to avoid this condition but it's not working....

```
        if(isset($_POST['wp_add_subscribe'])) {

        if($name && $mobile && $group) {

            if( (strlen($mobile) >= 11) && (substr($mobile, 0, 2) == get_option('wp_sms_mcc')) && (preg_match("([a-zA-Z])", $mobile) == 0) ) {

                $check_mobile = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM `{$table_prefix}sms_subscribes` WHERE `mobile` = '%s'", $mobile));

                if(!$check_mobile) {

                    $check = $wpdb->insert(
                        "{$table_prefix}sms_subscribes", 
                        array(
                            'date'      => $date,
                            'name'      => $name,
                            'mobile'    => $mobile,
                            'status'    => '1',
                            'group_ID'  => $group,
                        )
                    );

                    if($check) {
                        echo "<div class='updated'><p>" . sprintf(__('username <strong>%s</strong> was added successfully.', 'wp-sms'), $name) . "</div></p>";
                    }

                } else {
                    echo "<div class='error'><p>" . __('Phone number is repeated', 'wp-sms') . "</div></p>";
                }
            } else {
                echo "<div class='error'><p>" . __('Please enter a valid mobile number', 'wp-sms') . "</div></p>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<div class='error'><p>" . __('Please complete all fields', 'wp-sms') . "</div></p>";
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the 3rd `if` to

```
    if((strlen($mobile) >= 9) && (preg_match("([a-zA-Z])", $mobile) == 0)) {
```

`(substr($mobile, 0, 2) == get_option('wp_sms_mcc'))` is where this MCC (Mobile Country Code) is verified. I changed from 11 to 9, because the 2-digit country code is no longer required, but you can modify to your needs.

Comment: Same error message? This error will only happens if you provide a phone number with less than 9 numbers or with letters [a-zA-Z]. Is any of this your case?

Comment: No, it's not, unless its a client-side verification. Modify the error message on this script to another thing and run again. Which error does it give to you? Same error or the message you changed?

Comment: i am changing the file wp-sms.php

Comment: Which means: its a client-side verification. Try to find this error message in your HTML page (inside `script` block or javascript file).

Comment: As you have double verification (client and server side), you'll need to modify both. The modification I recommended works for server-side, as you asked, but as no client-side code (HTML+js) was provided I can't do much. Get your HTML code and ask a new question, if you prefer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64914/discussion-between-anakbhai-gida-and-rodrigo-berriel).